# Slug Taken, Cant Find Which Page

Tags: slug

I'm working on a friends site and I am attempting to update the slug `example.com/blah` but when I update the slug/url to `/blah` and click ok it updates it to `/blah-2`.

This means that there is an existing page/post with this setting. I searched the trash/etc in both pages and posts and I cannot find one. I hopped into the DB to take a look around and I wasn't able to find it either in the DB. Albeit, I'm no pro (beginner in this db schema). Where can I find what page/post has this slug so that I can fix this mess?

DB queries, plugins to help, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[The slug is the poorly named `post_name` column in the `$wpdb->posts` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_posts). Drop this into your theme templates somewhere-- `header.php`, for example-- and you should see any posts with a matching slug:

```
$q = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'name' => 'hello-world',
  )
);
var_dump($q->request);
var_dump($q->posts);
```

You can tweak the arguments for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you feel you need to.

Comment: Excellent help. This helped me figure out what my issue was - using a numeric slug on a page.

Comment: Great approach!

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I was attempting to use a numeric slug for a page which is not allowed. See - [Can I use a number for a post/page slug?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/481/can-i-use-a-number-for-a-post-page-slug)