# Slug is already taken - how do I find the original item

Tags: slug

I have a similar problem to this post:
[Slug Taken, Cant Find Which Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142542/slug-taken-cant-find-which-page)

I'm needing to create a page with slug /harvest but this is apparently already taken as WP insists my slug must be /harvest-2. This is a large complex site with a long history (I'm updating it) and 'harvest' is a common term.

- There is no page or post in trash
- No taxonomy or CPT called Harvest
- I've run the function given in the post above. Nothing shows except my new page and other items with terms including 'harvest' (eg 'harvesters' etc...).
- No media items or menu items are currently called 'harvest'. There was but I have changed it.
- I've installed 'Slugs Manager' plugin and removed any legacy slugs

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had previously located a media item with /harvest and fixed the slug but its NAME was still 'harvest'. I couldn't lfind where to change this so deleted and re-uploaded it.

Fixed.